# Codeigniter's Pagination first & last links not displaying

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I've checked and tried the user_guides, but nothing is working for me.

So here it is, My pagination configuration

```
$config['base_url']         = $getSiteUrl; //Pagination Url
$config['total_rows']       = $totalRows; //Total Number of records
$config['per_page']         = $perPage; //Number of records per page
$config['page_query_string']= TRUE;
$config['query_string_segment'] = "page";
$choice                     = $config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"];
$config["num_links"]        = floor($choice);
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;

//config for bootstrap pagination class integration
$config['full_tag_open']    = '<ul class="pagination">';
$config['full_tag_close']   = '</ul>';
$config['first_link']       = "&lt;&lt; First";
$config['last_link']        = "Last &gt;&gt;";
$config['first_tag_open']   = $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['first_tag_close']  = $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['prev_link']        = '&laquo';
$config['prev_tag_open']    = '<li class="prev">';
$config['prev_tag_close']   = '</li>';
$config['next_link']        = '&raquo';
$config['next_tag_open']    = '<li>';
$config['next_tag_close']   = '</li>';
$config['cur_tag_open']     = '<li class="active"><a>';
$config['cur_tag_close']    = '</a></li>';
$config['num_tag_open']     = '<li>';
$config['num_tag_close']    = '</li>';
```

The above configuration works good, except `First` and `Last` links.

Comment: `&gth;` is mistyped?

Comment: thanks for your response :), agreed. but this isn't helping..

Comment: How do you know the problem lies with the config? What error entails that it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change:

```
&raquo -> &raquo;
```

and

```
&laquo -> &laquo;
```

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean that it does not work? Is it possible to look at the generated HTML?

Comment: I mean, its the problem in config somewhere, which I'm unable to figure out. I can see numbered links, prev and next links, but no first and last links in the HTML.

Comment: Did you try to avoid a double assignment?
$config['first_tag_open'] = $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>' change to $config['first_tag_open'] = "<li>"; $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>'